# Error when passing @query parameter to sp_send_dbmail

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm running into a problem trying to execute a query inside of a call to `sp_send_dbmail`, using the `@query` parameter. My query works on it's own but once I put it within the '' the `@query` parameter when calling `sp_send_dbmail` it fails with incorrect syntax errors:

```
@query = 'SELECT DISTINCT "IINFO"."I_FIRST", "IINFO"."I_LASTNAME", "IINFO"."I_EMAIL", "STAY"."S_ADATE", "STAY"."S_GSTTYPE"
 FROM   "V1Data"."dbo"."STAY" "STAY" 
 INNER JOIN "V1Data"."dbo"."IINFO" "IINFO" 
    ON "STAY"."S_IRECID" = "IINFO"."I_RECID"
 WHERE  "STAY"."S_GSTTYPE"=''OWNER'' 
   AND  "STAY"."S_ADATE" >= DATEADD(day,-1,GETDATE())
   AND  "STAY"."S_ADATE" <= DATEADD(day,+7,GETDATE())
 ORDER BY S_ADATE ASC',
```

Error that I get:

> Msg 22050, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
>   Error formatting query, probably invalid parameters
>
> Msg 14661, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_send_dbmail, Line 517
>   Query execution failed: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server TCCHECKDB, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'I_FIRST'.

Comment: try removing the unnecessary `"` around the table and field names and see what you get

Comment: SQL Server use  `[]` to identify fields and tables name

Comment: Where does the title come into play? `rows based on next Saturday`

Comment: Is your @query variable of type `NVARCHAR`? The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx) for `sp_send_dbmail` specifies that the `@query` parameter is of type `NVARCHAR(MAX)`.